# build tor-browser on Linux aarch64 (Raspberry Pi 4)

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, arm, tor

I am trying to build `torbrowser` on a Linux (kali) machine running on Raspberry Pi4 (`ARMv8`=`aarch64`) but cannot figure out how. I cannot use normal `tor` (the one installed with `sudo apt install tor` or built from [source](https://dist.torproject.org/tor-0.4.4.6.tar.gz)). I tried to google around and looked at several posts here but cannot find a way to do it. Moreover, tor-browser-build now uses `rbm` that makes it even more difficult to work around

Any help is really appreciated!

Comment: Is there a particular reason to do it on Kali?

Comment: @AdminBee not really, it's just the OS I had in the machine, but it won't make any difference to use debian or anything else on `aarch64`

Comment: Under these circumstances I would recommend _not_ to use Kali, since (as you might know) that distribution is actually not meant as a desktop or development OS (let alone a base for an embedded system), but rather a specialized tool for security testers, and very user-unfriendly.

Comment: sure, I can switch to debian, but I would have the same problem as the point is the `aarch64` not the OS

Comment: Please let me know if you have any luck. I'm in a similar position trying to build IceCat for the aarch64 Raspberry Pi OS. Though, for me, I do not know of any issues with building, my problem is more not yet knowing how to build.

Comment: Hi @cccnrc as far as I see there is no build yet for Tor Browser Linux/ARM (x86_64 build arch) see [upstream](https://gitweb.torproject.org/). By the way they seems working on it see this contributor [thread](https://gitlab.torproject.org/tpo/applications/tor-browser-build/-/issues/32355) but they are still discussing this [build](https://notabug.org/JeremyRand/tor-browser-build/src/armhf-esr91). I am also interested to build tor-browser on Linux arch64 (Raspberry Pi 4) so I hope someone can make it done works!